# Item delete buttons in a table?

Tags: html

this is a simple html question but I would like to know the correct way of doing it.

I have a table in my page, with tabular data, and it's a display of items in the database. I build the table dynamically with php, and just output html.

I want to add a column "delete this entry" with a button/link/picture on every line, and when it's clicked, my page refreshes and php knows which itemID should be deleted.

The question is not about php, but about the html part.

How can I make the delete-button compliant with standards? Here's an incorrect solution:

```
<table>
<form action='#' method='post'>
<tr>
<td>Item 1</td>
<td><input type='hidden' name='id' value='1'><input type='submit' value='X'></td>
</tr>
</form>
<form action='#' method='post'>
<tr>
<td>Item 2</td>
<td><input type='hidden' name='id' value='2'><input type='submit' value='X'></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
```

Anyone an idea on a good solution? I'd prefer not to use much javascript, if it can be avoided.
Thanks in advance!

Edit: actually, I have a secret second question too: what if i were to want to do inline editing (after pressing an Edit button), as in: make the  cells with the values contain  boxes, and a submit button at the last cell?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

You could go with a simple **authenticated** GET procedure, like this:

```
<a href="showResults.php?action=delete&item=112">Delete</a>
```

Note the `action` and `item` values in the URL. These would be evaluated before the database is called and the results are printed in `showResults.php`. Your PHP (on showResults.php) would start with a block of logic that checks to see if any actions were requested, such as *delete*. If an action is present, it checks to see if an *item* is as well. I will then do whatever authentication necessary to ensure the user has sufficient rights to do this action to this item.

Next it would query the database (now lacking said item assuming the deletion was successful) and redraw the page. The links would be built within your loop used to create the many table-rows:

```
<?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
<tr>
  <td>
    <a href="sr.php?action=delete&item=<?php print $product->id; ?>">Delete</a>
  </td>
  <td>
    <p><?php print $product->title; ?></p>
  </td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Yes, I could, but that's bad because google accesses that link when it scrapes. I admit it probably won't scrape dynamic pages, but still it's not a good solution in my opinion.

Comment: Tominator, don't show the link unless the user browsing is authenticated.

Comment: If the link is only available to authenticated users, Google will never know it exists.

Comment: It's true what you say about google. This is probably the best solution. Thanks :) Would have an idea about the 'secret question' I added in the edit?

Comment: Tom, your secret question isn't that difficult. Ask it next, as an entirely new question :)

Comment: Actually one of the other repliers gave me the solution to the 'secret', so I can combine all of you into one solution in my head. Thanks!

Comment: The bad thing about GET methods in this scenario is that GET requests are meant to be cachable by the browsers and delete requests change the state .. implying it should not be cached!

Comment: Please do NOT delete something on a GET request. It doesn't matter if you include the link in your HTML or not (at some point some bot will find the address and delete everything just by sending a GET request). Use DELETE, or (i.e., in HTML forms that only support GET and POST) POST as a fallback. No bot will send an HTTP POST/PUT/DELETE to your address.

Comment: @basic6 Very good suggestions, but please consider the request wouldn't/shouldn't delete anything unless the session is authenticated. It would, obviously, be unwise to delete things at the command of an anonymous unathenticated user. This answer is pretty old though, and I think I could improve it a bit. Will do so a.s.a.p.; thank you.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson: Make that "shouldn't". I know what you mean and you're right, but I still wouldn't abuse GET to modify data (GET methods should be const) because it's just not right. Any HTTP client could send tons of GET requests to any resource. If it's not a Google bot, it may be some Browser addon that's doing some pre-fetching and boom, it pre-fetched a page that deletes something in the database. I know that this is isn't as simple in plain PHP as with certain Perl web frameworks, but as an alternative to DELETE, use POST; just anything other than GET.

Comment: @basic6 Thank you for the helpful comments, you're absolutely right. HTTP verbs exist for specific reasons, and those reasons should be considered when performing actions against a server. In 2009, I didn't understand that as well.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson: You're welcome. I hope these comments will be useful to someone who might find this question on Google.

Answer (score 2):

Why not isolate the forms and pass the ID to the action page?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Item 1</td>
        <td><form action='action.php?id=1' method='post'><input type='submit' value='X'></form></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Item 2</td>
        <td><form action='action.php?id=2' method='post'><input type='submit' value='X'></form></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This works, but I have a secret second question: what if i were to want to do inline editing, as in: make the <td> cells with the values contain <input type='text'> boxes, and a submit button at the last cell?

Comment: Will the input boxes be rendered on the page from the server, or will it be a javascript function to make the cell contents editable? Just wondering because it can change the way to make this work.

Comment: On the server in this case.. the ajax solution will be later on :) But I've gathered the required intel already from the other posters, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You can write names of submit buttons as set of facts and their values, for example *name='set1(fact1:value2,fact2:value2,...)'*. Then search for submitted set and get fact value. A PHP class **PageFacts** below can do this. You can check if set is posted  using condition **if (PageFacts::is('del'))** and get value of fact with statement **$itemID = PageFacts::get('del', 'id')**.
Form with submit buttons can look like:

```
<form method="post">
    ... item [0] text/input
    <input type="submit" name="del(id:0)" value="Del">
    ... item [1] text/input
    <input type="submit" name="del(id:1)" value="Del">
    ... item [2] text/input
    <input type="submit" name="del(id:2)" value="Del">
    ...
    ...
    <input type="submit" name="chng" value="Chng">
</form>
```

An example of PHP code that deletes table item with itemID can be:

```
if (PageFacts::is('del')) {
    $itemID = PageFacts::get('del', 'id');
    // Delete $itemID
    deleteTableItem($itemID);
}

// or for multiple facts like del(cid:2,id:0)
if (PageFacts::is('del')) {
    $cartID = PageFacts::get('del', 'cid');
    $itemID = PageFacts::get('del', 'id');

    // Delete $itemID from $cartID
    deleteCartItem($cartID, $itemID);
}
```

**PageFacts** PHP code:

```
class PageFacts {

    // Gets fact value from posted set
    // $s ... name of a set
    // $f ... name of a fact
    // returns - value of fact $f in set $s
    //         - TRUE  if set $s exists but fact $f doesn't exist
    //         - FALSE if set $s doesn't exist
    public static function get($s, $f = NULL) {
        // Regex pattern to search for set $s
        $ps = "/^\s*$s\s*\((.*)\)\s*$/";
        // Search POSTed names (variable $v is not used)
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $v) {
            $ok = preg_match($ps, $key, $matches);
            if ($ok && isset($matches[1])) {
                // If $f is not passed return TRUE, means set $s exists regardless of fact $f
                if (!isset($f)) {
                    return TRUE;
                }
                // Otherwise return value of fact $f
                // use regex pattern to search in list of fact:value items separated by a comma
                $pf = "/^\s*$f\s*\:\s*(.+)\s*$/";
                foreach (explode(',', $matches[1]) as $fv) {
                    $ok = preg_match($pf, $fv, $matches);
                    if ($ok && isset($matches[1])) {
                        return $matches[1];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
    // Checks if set $s is posted
    public static function is($s) {
        return self::get($s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of messy, but going off of what Agent said, you could do something like this to get a text input in there too:

```
<form action='action.php?id=1' method='POST'>
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>Item 1</td>
       <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
       <td><input type='submit' value='X'></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>

<form action='action.php?id=2' method='POST'>
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>Item 2</td>
       <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
       <td><input type='submit' value='X'></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: I doubt this would keep my layout intact, but Agent suggested to use 1 form, with the table in it, and multiple submit buttons, each with a unique value-string, to parse in php later on. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: you can **always** match the design to fit the functionality ;)

Comment: why not a form for each table row instead for each table?

Comment: @aseychell - It's not semantically correct. See Juraj Blahunka's answer and the corresponding comments

Answer (score -1):

Add a **submit button** to each form and send the operation you want to execute as value attribute of each button

```
<table>
    <form action='#' method='post'>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td><input type='hidden' name='id' value='1'><input type='submit' value='X'></td>
            <td><button type="submit" value="remove" name="op">Remove</button></td>
            <td><button type="submit" value="edit" name="op">Edit</button></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the reason I said my presented solution is bad, is that it's not allowed to put a <form> tag between a table and a tr.

Comment: what about wrapping the whole table in a form and then add for each tr a simple button with value="del-1231" or value="edit-1231" which is easily parsable, this is complete valid solution

Comment: Did you know that in IE, it submits the text between the <button></button>, and not the value=''? And in an input type=submit, I can't say value='edit-1234' because that would look ugly..

Comment: well you can still distinguish between various inputs with "name" attribute (name=edit value=123, name=delete value=123)